# Memcpy change the pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy, buffer-overflow

My task is to exploit a program which has two lines of code of memcpy. So I'm now studying memcpy and just found this.

```
int main() {
    char a[10] = "123456789";
    cout<<a<<endl;
    char b[5];
    memcpy(b, a, 10);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<a-5<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
}
```

and the output will be:

```
123456789
6789
123456789
123456789
```

Any idea Why the pointer of a changed here?

Comment: Works correctly on local machine, check again

Comment: `cout<<a<<endl;` doesn't output the pointer value, but the character contents!

Comment: 'b' is having memory of 5 byte and '10' bytes being added to from 'a'. Hence you are overwriting some stack memory of other variable! Undefined!

Comment: @Digital_Reality I think you missed `"My task is to exploit a program"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `a` is an array, not a pointer. On the stack, there's a significant difference, which I describe in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357449/391161).
2. `a` is higher than `b` on the stack, so when you copy `10` bytes from `a` to `b`, you have gone `5` bytes off the end of `b` and replaced the first `5` bytes of `a`. Note that this specific behavior is highly dependent on the compiler flags and the compiler version, and is generally speaking **undefined**.
3. As an additional note, you have not printed the address of `a`, which is what I assume you meant by `pointer`. You have instead printed the value stored there.