# difference between pointer to an array and pointer to the first element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers

`int (*arr)[5]` means `arr` is a pointer-to-an-array of 5 integers. Now what exactly is this pointer?

Is it the same if I declare `int arr[5]` where `arr` is the pointer to the first element?

Is `arr` from both the examples are the same? If not, then what exactly is a pointer-to-an-array?

Comment: [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At runtime, a pointer is a "just a pointer" regardless of what it points to, the difference is a semantic one; pointer-to-array conveys a different meaning (to the compiler) compared with pointer-to-element

When dealing with a pointer-to-array, you are pointing to an array of a specified size - and the compiler will ensure that you can only point-to an array of that size.

i.e.  this code will compile

```
int theArray[5];
int (*ptrToArray)[5];
ptrToArray = &theArray;    // OK
```

but this will break:

```
int anotherArray[10];
int (*ptrToArray)[5];
ptrToArray = &anotherArray;    // ERROR!
```

When dealing with a pointer-to-element, you may point to any object in memory with a matching type.   (It doesn't necessarily even need to be in an array; the compiler will not make any assumptions or restrict you in any way)

i.e.

```
int theArray[5];
int* ptrToElement = &theArray[0];  // OK - Pointer-to element 0
```

and..

```
int anotherArray[10];
int* ptrToElement = &anotherArray[0];   // Also OK!
```

In summary, the data type `int*` does not imply any knowledge of an array, however the data type `int (*)[5]` implies an array, which must contain exactly 5 elements.

Comment: According to your explanation, though, `int* anotherPtr = theArray;` shouldn't work.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That is just short-hand syntax for `int* anotherPtr = &theArray[0];`  They both do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Well, it's an implicit conversion. It tends to cause confusion as many believe that the array already or always is the pointer to its first element.

Comment: @Potatoswatter fair point, I've edited it out since it's not really needed for the answer.

Comment: All this talk of The Compiler sounds quite scary. There is the C++ standard, and compilers just try to implement the rules set out in it.

Answer (score 19):

### Theory

First off some theory (you can skip to the "Answers" section but I suggest you to read this as well):

```
int arr[5]
```

this is an array and "arr" is **not** the pointer to the first element of the array. **Under specific circumstances (i.e. passing them as lvalues to a function) they decay into pointers**: you lose the ability of calling `sizeof` on them.

Under normal circumstances an array is an array and a pointer is a pointer and they're two totally different things.

When dealing with a decayed pointer and the pointer to the array you wrote, they behave exactly the same but there's a caveat: an array of type T can decay into a pointer of type T, but only once (or one level-deep). The newly created decayed type cannot further decay into anything else.

This means that a bidimensional array like

```
int array1[2][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}};
```

can't be passed to

```
void function1(int **a);
```

because it would imply a two-levels decaying and that's not allowed (you lose how elements of the array are laid out). The followings would instead work:

```
void function1(int a[][2]);
void function1(int a[2][2]);
```

In the case of a 1-dimensional array passed as lvalue to a function you can have it decayed into a simple pointer and in that case **you can use it as you would with any other pointer**.

---

### Answers

Answering your questions:

```
int (*arr)[5]
```

this is a pointer to an array and you can think of the "being an array of 5 integers" as being its type, i.e. you can't use it to point to an array of 3 integers.

```
int arr[5]
```

this is an array and will always behave as an array except when you pass it as an lvalue

```
int* ptrToArr = arr;
```

in that case the array decays (with all the exceptions above I cited) and you get a **pointer** and you can use it as you want.

And: no, they're not equal otherwise something like this would be allowed

```
int (*arr)[5]
int* ptrToArr = arr; // NOT ALLOWED

Error cannot convert ‘int (*)[5]’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
```

they're both pointers but the difference is in their type.

Comment: Unfortunately that I had always been told that `arr` is exactly equivalent to `&arr[0]`, except the case in applying `sizeof` on them. Then I found many annoying inconsistency and weird behaviors when thinking as this way. I like this answer! +1

Comment: You keep saying pass as an lvalue. Don't you mean rvalue?

Answer (score 8):

A pointer to an array is a pointer to an array of a certain type. The type includes the type of the elements, as well as the size. You cannot assign an array of a different type to it:

```
int (*arr)[5]; 
int a[5];
arr = &a; // OK
int b[42];
arr = &b; // ERROR: b is not of type int[5].
```

A pointer to the first element of an array can point to the beginning of any array with the right type of element (in fact, it can point to any element in the array):

```
int* arr; 
int a[5];
arr = &a[0]; // OK
int b[42];
arr = &b[0]; // OK
arr = &b[9]; // OK
```

Note that in C and C++, arrays decay to pointers to the type of their elements in certain contexts. This is why it is possible to do this:

```
int* arr; 
int a[5];
arr = a; // OK, a decays to int*, points to &a[0]
```

Here, the type of `arr` (`int*`) is not the same as that of `a` (`int[5]`), but `a` decays to an `int*` pointing to its first element, making the assignment legal.

Answer (score 7):

Pointer to array and pointer to first element of array both are different. In case of `int (*arr)[5]`, `arr` is pointer to chunk of memory of `5` `int`. Dereferencing `arr` will give the entire row. In case of `int arr[5]`, `arr` decays to pointer to first element. Dereferencing `arr` will give the first element.
In both cases starting address is same but both the pointers are of different type.

> Is it the same if i declare `int arr[5]` where `arr` is the pointer to the first element? is `arr` from both example are same? if not, then what exactly is a pointer to an array?

No. To understand this see the diagram for the function<sup>**1**</sup>:

```
void f(void) {
    int matrix[4][2] = { {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7} };
    char s[] = "abc";
    int i = 123;
    int *p1 = &matrix[0][0];
    int (*p2)[2] = &matrix[0];
    int (*p3)[4][2] = &matrix;
    /* code goes here */
}
```

[image]

**All three pointers certainly allow you to locate the `0` in `matrix[0][0]`**, and if you convert these pointers to ‘byte addresses’ and print them out with a `%p` directive in `printf()`, **all three are quite likely to produce the same output** (on a typical modern computer).  But the `int *` pointer, `p1`, points only to a single `int`, as circled in black.  The red pointer, `p2`, whose type is `int (*)[2]`, points to two `int`s, and the blue pointer -- the one that points to the entire matrix -- really does point to the entire matrix.
These differences affect the results of both pointer arithmetic and the unary `*` (indirection) operator.  Since `p1` points to a single `int`, **`p1 + 1` moves forward by a single `int`**.  The black circle[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrtyJ.gif) is only as big as one `int`, and `*(p1 + 1)` is just the next int, whose value is 1.  Likewise, `sizeof *p1` is just `sizeof(int)` (probably 4).

Since `p2` points to an entire ‘array 2 of int’, however, **`p2 + 1` will move forward by one such array**.  The result would be a pointer pointing to a red circle going around the `{2,3}` pair.  Since the result of an indirection operator is an object, `*(p2 + 1)` is that entire array object, which may fall under The Rule.  If it does fall under The Rule, the object will become instead a pointer to its first element, i.e., the `int` currently holding `2`.  If it does not fall under The Rule -- for instance, in `sizeof *(p2 + 1)`, which puts the object in object context -- it will remain the entire array object.  This means that `sizeof *(p2 + 1)` (and `sizeof *p2` as well, of course) is `sizeof(int[2])` (probably 8).

---

<sub>**1** Above content has been taken from [More Words about Arrays and Pointers](http://web.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html).</sub>

Comment: did you make the graph yourself? :D

Comment: @MarcoA.; No. This is from a research paper.

Answer (score 2):

The address of the whole array, and the address of the first element, are defined to be the same, since arrays in C++ (and C) have no intrinsic padding besides that of the constituent objects.

However, the types of these pointers are different. Until you perform some kind of typecast, comparing an `int *` to an `int (*)[5]` is apples to oranges.

If you declare `arr[5]`, then `arr` is *not* a pointer to the first element. It is the array object. You can observe this as `sizeof( arr )` will be equal to `5 * sizeof (int)`. An array object *implicitly converts* to a pointer to its first element.

A pointer to an array does not implicitly convert to anything, which may be the other cause of your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `int arr[5]`, you are creating *an array* of five `int` on the stack. This takes up size equal to the size of five ints.

If you write `int (*arr)[5]`, you are creating *a pointer* to an array of five `int` on the stack. This takes up size equal to the size of a pointer.

If it is not clear from the above, the pointer has **separate** storage from the array, and can point at anything, but the array name cannot be assigned to point at something else.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357449/391161) for more details.