# Why are `&array` and `array` pointing to the same address?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Until now, I thought an array is the same as a pointer. But I found a weird case:

#### code

```
int array[5] = { 10,11,12,13,14};

std::cout << array << std::endl;
std::cout << &array << std::endl;
std::cout << &array[0] << std::endl;

int *pArray = new int[5];

std::cout << pArray << std::endl;
std::cout << &pArray << std::endl;
std::cout << &pArray[0] << std::endl;
```

#### output

```
0x7ffeed730ad0
0x7ffeed730ad0
0x7ffeed730ad0

0x7f906d400340
0x7ffeed730a30
0x7f906d400340
```

As you can see `array` and `&array` have the same value.  But `pArray` and `&pArray` have different value. If array is same as pointer, address of array should be different from array. 
How can `array` and `&array` be the same? If `array` and `&array` are same, what is the address of the memory which holds the array values?

Comment: It's because an array is not a pointer. In the case of an array `&a` and `a` are the same thing. In the case of a pointer `p` is the address the pointer points to, and `&p` is the address where the pointer value is stored.

Comment: Here we can witness the inconsistency of the language. `new int[5]` should return a pointer to `int[5]`, not a pointer to `int`.

Comment: related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104482/difference-between-pointer-to-an-array-and-pointer-to-the-first-element-of-an-ar

Comment: @geza how is that different? A pointer is a pointer

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: that's not that simple. This inconsistency has some consequences. Like, it is not that simple to get a pointer to the array from the pointer to the first element.

Comment: @geza I don't follow. If you have a pointer to the first element of an array you have a pointer to the array itself. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552713/can-stdlaunder-be-used-to-convert-an-object-pointer-to-its-enclosing-array-poi. And maybe there are other questions about this issue.

Comment: @geza That would require adding the (ugly) variable-length types, or alternative means of creating dynamic arrays.

Comment: Ah, I stay clear from all that `reinterpret_cast` nonsense.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Plain `array` decays to a pointer to its first element, it's equal to `&array[0]`. The first element also happens to start at the same address as the array itself. Hence `&array == &array[0]`.

But it's important to note that the *types* are different:

- The type of `&array[0]` is (in your example) `int*`.
- The type of `&array` is `int(*)[5]`.

The relationship between `&array[0]` and `&array` might be easier if I show it a little more "graphically" (with pointers added):

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| array[0] | array[1] | array[2] | array[3] | array[4] |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
^
|
&array[0]
|
&array
```

As an extra addendum, `array` decays to a pointer to its first element, that is `array` decays to `&array[0]` and will thus have the same type.

---

Things are different with pointers though. The pointer `pArray` is pointing to some memory, the value of `pArray` is the location of that memory. This is what you get when you use `pArray`. It is also the same as `&pArray[0]`.

When you use `&pArray` you get a pointer *to the pointer*. That is, you get the location (address) of the variable `pArray` itself. Its type is `int**`.

Somewhat graphical with the pointer `pArray` it would be something like this

```
+--------+       +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| pArray | ----> | pArray[0] | pArray[1] | pArray[2] | pArray[3] | pArray[4] | ... |
+--------+       +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
^                ^
|                |
&pArray          &pArray[0]
```

<sub>[Note the `...` at the end of the "array", that's because pointers retains no information about the memory it points to. A pointer is only pointing to a specific location, the "first" element of the "array". Treating the memory as an "array" is up to the programmer.]</sub>

Comment: Not sure that `(void*)&array` should be equal to `(void*)(&array[0])` BTW. (`&array[0]` and `array` should).

Comment: @Jarod42 An array overlaps exactly with all individual elements of the array. There's no "padding" or "gaps" before, between or after the elements of the array.

Comment: I mean `int (&)[N]` decays to `int*` and so results in same pointer, `int (*)[N]` and `int*` are unrelated types. I don't think they have to be equal (once casted to "common" `void*`) even if it seems simpler to implement it that way.

Comment: @Jarod42 I already mentioned the different types, but that doesn't matter. I don't have any quotes from the C++ specification unfortunately, but I distinctly remember that there's something in it that does say that `(void*) &array == (void*) &array[0]` must still be true (even though it has to be puzzled together from a couple of different sections). Otherwise something like `(*(&array))[0]` wouldn't work.

Comment: `*&a` is "noop" (for types without evil unary operator &), So your example is not the right one :/ .

Comment: @Jarod42 While a compiler is allowed to optimize that noop, consider a naive non-optimizing compiler. Or how about the convoluted `void* p = &array; int (*a)[5] = (int(*)[5]) p; std::cout << (*a)[0];`? If `(void*) &array == (void*) &array[0]` is not true, then the dereference of `a` would not give the original array and the indexing of it would not be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188828/discussion-between-jarod42-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: How do you read `int(*)[5]` ? Pointer to array of 5 elements of type int ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry I had went home. I also often need time to form my train of thoughts when writing, so that kind of makes me dislike chats.

Comment: i had the same question... what i can not get properly is the folllowing: lets say we have the int array[10]. array then is a pointer to the first element (&array[0]). Seems ok at first thought but if &array is &array[0] then that means that array[0] holds the address of the array (which it does not). How is that possible? Or is it that array word is not actually a pointer but when we write it is "substituted" as the address (and thus when we write &array we say the address of that address)? I'm sorry if i make syntactical mistakes , i hope i'm clear... Thanks in advance

Comment: @ΝίκοςΑντωνετσής Both `&array` and `&array[0]` points to the same location in memory, but they are different types. `&array` is a pointer to an "array of 10 `int` values", or `int (*)[10]`. While `&array[0]` is a "pointer to a single `int` element" of the array, with the type `int *`. It's the same with `&array[6]`, it's also a "pointer to a single `int` element" and also have the type `int *`.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΑντωνετσής Also consider something simple like `int var;`. When you apply the pointer-to operator `&var` you get a "pointer to a single `int` element", with the type `int *`, as well.

Comment: Maybe i miss something, thats why i'm stuck.  The problem for me is that if array is a pointer, then  &array is where this pointer  is stored . And to my logic if array and &array have the same value we have a location in memory which contains its location. But this location should hold the first element of the array.

Comment: Also isn't it than when we write &array, we actually write  &&array[0] ?

Comment: @ΝίκοςΑντωνετσής No. First because `&&` will be parsed as the logical AND operator. And secondly because the result of `&array[0]` is a *rvalue* and it's not possible to get a pointer to an rvalue. And thirdly, a pointer to the array, and a pointer to an element of that array, are *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer to an element. A pointer to the array is a pointer to the whole array as a single entity.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΑντωνετσής You say "if array is a pointer", and that's where your confusion is comming from. An array is an array and ***not*** a pointer. And a pointer is *not* an array. But an array can *decay* to a pointer (to its first element). So `array` on its own might be the array itself, as one single entity. Or if a pointer to a single element is expected then it decay to a pointer to its first element (`&array[0]`). But `array` itself is still the whole array.

Comment: Probably that's why... Well i was expecting an equivalence between: `int *hello= (int * ) malloc (40); hello=(int*)&hello;` and `int hi[10];` when using `hello` , `&hello` , `hello[0]` ,`&hello[0]`  and `hi `  ,`&hi `,  `hi[0]`, `&hi[0]` , which breaks when i do `hello[0] =1 ;`  (but on the othe hand i can do `hi[0] =1;`)

Comment: @ΝίκοςΑντωνετσής The assignment `hello=(int*)&hello` is wrong. That you need a cast to silence the compiler should be a sign of that.

Answer (score 1):

An array of X's has to behave like a pointer to a contiguous list of X's in memory much like a pointer. However, nowhere is it written where the memory that stores that data is must be it's own address and writablej. In the case of an explicit pointer there is a new allocation for this address (in this case the stack) however for an array, on the stack, the compiler already know where the contents are so no new allocation is needed.

As a consequence, its not safe to treat it as a pointer, without indexing. e.g.:

```
pArray = nullptr; // This is a memory leak, unless a copy is taken, but otherwise fine.
array = nullptr; // This is will make the compiler upset
```