# Creating a Multidimensional array in C++ not allowing int**

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

In C++ when I perform the following action,

```
int* b = new int[5];
```

`new int[5];` returns an `int*` which I use `b` to point to.

However, when performing,

```
int** c = new int[5][10];
```

I receive an error, `cannot convert ‘int (*)[10]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization`.

Why does this syntax not work, however it will in other situations such as,

```
int** matrix = new int* [5];
for(int i=0; i < d1; i++){
    matrix[i] = new int[10];
}
```

In the above example, `matrix` is a pointer to an array which contains 5 elements of type `int *`, therefore is `int** c = new int[5][10];` not accomplishing the same thing? I am creating `c`, a pointer to an array of 5 elements of type `int *`, therefore the type should be `int**`?

My question I guess is simply, why would `int** c = new int[5][10];` throw me a `cannot convert ‘int (*)[10]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization` but it works in the other example provided?

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers and vice versa.

Comment: `new int[5][10]` creates an array of 5 arrays of size 10. 5 rows of 10 columns. It's a pointer to an array of size 10.

Comment: `new int[5][10]` creates a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Also, please don't use pointers and `new` for plain arrays. If the size is known at compile-time and are not expected to change, consider `std::array`. Otherwise use `std::vector`.

Comment: You will get burned by believing that an `int **` is the same as a `int[5][10]`.  Either you work with `int[5][10]` throughout your code, or you work with `int **` throughout your code -- you cannot mix and match them, pretend one is the other, etc.  If you dynamically built your "2D-array" using `int**` as the base, then you have to use `int **` as parameters, return values, etc.

Comment: Just use `std::array` or `std::vector` already and forget about C-style arrays and ditch all that manual memory management. You'll have fewer bugs, simpler code and sleep better at night.

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104482/difference-between-pointer-to-an-array-and-pointer-to-the-first-element-of-an-ar

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion Thanks. I've been reading the replies but I am not sure any actually answered it to the degree I actually understood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think `int** c = new int[5][10];` and `int** matrix = new int* [5];` are the same syntax, because they're definitely not.

First, this is how you can accomplish this:

```
typedef int row10_t[10];

row10_t* matrix = new int[5][10];
```

Now you can use it

```
matrix[0][1] = 5;
matrix[3][5] = 4;
```

The issue though, is you've tagged this as a C++ question, but this is all entirely C programming. You really should do it the C++ way if you plan on doing this with C++ as others have warned; there are many advantages. You could do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(5,std::vector<int>(10,3));

matrix[1][0] = 5;
```

You'll need to initialize the vectors with however you need. Maybe not this way, maybe exactly like this, but that is up to you. In a vector, the values must be set before you can access them because the vector needs to allocate the proper space for the data.

You can even use a pointer on this since vectors use contiguous memory allocation, but again, this is C++. The proper way to iterate a vector is to use the iterator, not a pointer. Here is an example using a range based loop for better readability:

```
for(auto& row : matrix)
{
    for(auto& col : row)
    {
        std::cout << col << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which will output the matrix with our change in it:

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

The 3s are what we set as initial values for every entry, but you can set this to whatever you want.